# Replacing default android icons?

Tags: android

I have made a launcher but i need it to replace the default android os icons. Such as gmail, browser, sms, and ect.

How would i do this??

I know how to link package names and drawables and i have that all correct, but the icon images are not changing. Anyone have any advice...

This is what i use in custom themes and other projects...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/com_android_browser_com_android_browser_browseractivity" />
</selector>
```

The file name is the package name for the icon and it goes in the drawables file...

Thanks,
SyndicateApps

Comment: i think you need to change your application icon?

Comment: Ya. thats for the the actual app icon. But i am wondering how to change all other icons. sort of like a theme

Comment: you can change it from manifest file

Comment: <application android:icon="@mylib:drawable/icon">

Comment: but i am not changing my icon. It is a launcher and i want to change, lets say, the browser icon. Not my app icon. And the package name for the browser is com.android.browser. my browser icon is@drawable/browser_icon. so how can i somehow link the package name to the drawable icon?????